# What is the antonym of "update"?

Tags: antonyms

For similar words, the antonym is obtained by simply substitute the substring *up* with *down* like in the following:

- *upgrade* - *downgrade*
- *upload* - *download*

What about *update*? I searched for something like *downdate* but it has very few occurrences and I'm not sure if it is only a rare used word or a wrong one.

---

#### A bit of context

The use is related to computer specific context. If I think of *update*'s meaning as up-to-the-current-date, then the word that I need to use should have the meaning of up-to-the-past-date. As suggested in an answer, good candidates can be *rollback*, *reverting* and *restoring*. However, all of them suggest the idea of modify something in order to make it equal to a past state. In my case it's a bit different. It's a chunk of code that works well with current version of some programming language API but since it needs to be run with an older version I modified it to be compatible with this older version. Maybe in this case I could just say 'updated to the previous API version' but I wonder if the use of *downdate* is correct.

Comment: If you need to use such word, can you provide some context?

Comment: @Jan Too long to answer in a comment. I updated (LOL) the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is reversing a process [particularly computer-related updates], I think the closest word is "[rollback](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rollback)" or "[reverting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revert)" to the previous version or idea. Windows systems have system "restore".

In the context of the state of being updated (i.e., up-to-date), then it's "[obsolete](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsolete)" or "[out-of-date](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of_date)".

I believe there are other possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "downdate" in those few dictionaries I checked. People sometimes use it to suggest someone to change a current version of a program to an older version, but this is not what you are asking.

So, you may want to use [**modify**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/modify) or one of its synonyms: **adapt, convert, customize, tweak**...or, simply, **make compatible**.